# Is there a metric space such that for a sequence of nonempty subsets $K_1 \supset K_2 ....$ the intersection of all subsets is empty?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, compactness

Is there a metric space $(X,d)$ such that for a sequence of $\emptyset \neq K_j \subset X$ with $K_1 \supset K_2 ....$ such that the intersection of all $\bigcap _{j\in \mathbb{N}}K_j$ is empty?

It seems very obvious that since all $K_j$ are not empty, there is an element in $K_1$ that is also in all $K_i$ with $i \geq 1$ and that this element this is an element of the intersection, which thus is nonempty.

However in the task it was specified that the metric space is **compact** and the subsets $K_j$ are **closed**. I have used neither in the argument above and cannot figure out a counterexample where it would be necessary to have the conditions to the sets.

Comment: I think you may be getting the inclusions backwards.  An element of $K_1$ does not have to be in all $K_i$ with $i\geq 1$, since $K_1$ is a superset, not a subset of them.

Comment: @EricWofsey I did not claim that any element of $K_1$ is an element of any further subset. However if for example $K_1 \supset K_2 \neq \emptyset$, then there exists an element in $K_1$ that is also an element in $K_2$

Comment: That gets you an element of both $K_1$ and $K_2$.  But what about an element of every single $K_i$ at once?

Comment: @EricWofsey You can use that argument iteratively for any pair $K_n \supset K_{n+1}$ and since $K_1 \supset K_n$ you get a point that is in all $K_i$

Comment: I would suggest thinking about what happens when you try that argument on the examples given in the answers.

Comment: I know, that one point may turn out to be the limit of a sequence that is not in $X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both conditions are necessary for the theorem to hold. Here are two examples:

**Sets are not closed:**

Consider the metric space $[0,1]$ with the usual metric, and the sets $K_n = (0,\frac{1}{n}]$. This space is compact, and the sets $K_n$ are nonempty and $K_n \supset K_{n+1}$. However, the intersection of these sets is empty: remark that the sets $K_n$ are not closed.

**Space is not compact:**

Consider the metric space $(0,1]$ with the usual metric, and the sets $K_n = (0,\frac{1}{n}]$. These sets are nonempty, we have $K_n \supset K_{n+1}$, and importantly: the sets are closed in $(0,1]$ (you may have to convince yourself of this). However, again, the intersection of these sets is empty: remark that the space is not compact.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, the intersection can be empty: let $X  =\mathbb{R}$ in the standard metric
and $K_n = [n, \infty)$ which are all closed. And if $x \in \mathbb{R}$, let $N$ be some integer above $x$, then $x \notin K_N$ so $x \notin \bigcap_n K_n$, so that $\bigcap_n K_n  =\emptyset$.

The nice thing is that this cannot happen if $X$ or some $K_n$ is compact.

Comment: Henno.Very nice answer, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Take the reals (with the usual topology) and $K_n=[n,+\infty)$.